# trying to put 1D array to a 2D array in specific order

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

I need to write a function that receives 1D array
for example: [2,5,3]
and i need to create the following 2D array:
[[2,-5,-3][-2,5,-3][-2,-5,3]

my code is:

```
    for (int i=0; i<vars.length; i++){

        for (int j=0; j<vars.length; j++)
            tempVars[j] = vars[j]*(-1);

        tempVars[i] = tempVars[i]*(-1);
        solution[i] = tempVars;
        
    }

    return solution ;
}
```

however the output I'm getting is: [[-2, -5, 3], [-2, -5, 3], [-2, -5, 3]]
the function put only the last 1D array in all the 2D array cells.
what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: From the looks of it you only create one array `tempVars` that you override in your loop and add multiple times to the `solution` array. You need to create one array for every possible result instead of using the same one again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@OH GOD SPIDERS was right. The `tempVars` arrays is added multiples times to `solutions`, so `solutions` is filled with 3 reference to the same array.

Use:

```
    for (int i=0; i<vars.length; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<vars.length; j++) {
            tempVars[j] = vars[j]*(-1);
        }


        tempVars[i] = tempVars[i]*(-1);
        solution[i] = tempVars.clone();

    }
```

The `clone()` in `solution[i] = tempVars.clone();` will ensure that a new array, cloned from `tempVars`, is put in `solution`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    int n=4;
    int a[]=new int[n];
    a[0]=2;
    a[1]=5;
    a[2]=3;
    a[3]=6;

    int a1[][]=process(a);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            System.out.print(a1[i][j]+" ");
        System.out.println();   
    }

    }


    public static int[][] process(int[] a)
    {
        int x=a.length;
        int a1[][]=new int[x][x];
        int i=0;

        for(int b=0;b<x;b++)
        {
            for(int c=0;c<x;c++)
            {
                if(c==i)
                    a1[b][c]=a[c];
                else
                    a1[b][c]=-1*a[c];
            }
            i++;
        }

        return a1;

    }
}
```

Here is the working demo of what you wanted. I have created a function which takes a 1D array and returns a 2D array just according to your requirement.

Comment: You can use `Arrays.toString(a1[i]);` to get a String containing the values of an array, instead of using `for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            System.out.print(a1[i][j]+" ");`

Answer (score 0):

```
    var data = [2,3,5];
    var counter = data.length;
    var finalArr=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
      var tmpArr = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
          if(i==j){
            tmpArr.push(-data[j]);
          }
          else{
          tmpArr.push(data[j]);
          }
       }
       finalArr.push(tmpArr);
    }
    console.log(finalArr)
```